# DataFrame Multiple Column Comparison using LAMBDA

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, lambda

I have a dataframe which contain some integer values, I want to create a new dataframe of the row only if multiple columns [col1, col3, col4] are not ALL zeroes.  Example:

```
      col1    col2        col3    col4    col5   col6
0        0    text1          3       0      22      0
1        9    text2         13      11      22      1
2        0    text3          0       0      22      0       # not valid
3        9    text4         13      11      22      0
4        0    text5          0       1      12      4
```

I am not sure if possible to do this with a single lambda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for any custom function at all.  We can just select the columns we want, do our boolean comparison, and then use that to index into your dataframe:

```
In [28]: df[["col1", "col3", "col4"]] == 0
Out[28]: 
    col1   col3   col4
0   True  False   True
1  False  False  False
2   True   True   True
3  False  False  False
4   True   True  False

In [29]: (df[["col1", "col3", "col4"]] == 0).all(axis=1)
Out[29]: 
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
dtype: bool

In [30]: df.loc[~(df[["col1", "col3", "col4"]] == 0).all(axis=1)]
Out[30]: 
   col1   col2  col3  col4  col5  col6
0     0  text1     3     0    22     0
1     9  text2    13    11    22     1
3     9  text4    13    11    22     0
4     0  text5     0     1    12     4
```

There are lots of similar ways to rewrite it (not all zeroes is any being nonzero, etc.)